# Compiling Spark Mllib using sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have been building some modifications inside Spark Mllib for a while now and every time I want to want to compile Spark, I have to do the following:

```
sbt update
sbt compile
sbt clean
sbt package
```

While this procedure produces what I want, I find it unnecessary to compile and package the other Spark modules. Is there a quick command to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the compile part, just do `sbt complie` which is incremental by default.

You might be able to package subsets of the project with something like `sbt mllib/package`.